# Adding options/arguments to installed applications permanently (flatpak)

Tags: ubuntu, pop-os

I have a concrete issue with the Spotify desktop app. By default it just shows me a blank screen because of hardware acceleration issues. To fix that I need to launch it with the `--disable-gpu` option. It is installed as a flatpak package from Pop shop. I figured that I can modify the related .desktop file to include the option: `~/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.spotify.Client/x86_64/stable/xxx/export/share/applications/com.spotify.Client.desktop`

However it seems that occasionally it gets overwritten, I guess because of updates.
So the question: Is there a better way to add options/arguments to installed flatpak apps? Ideally the change should survive an update.